# Printing a field with additional dots in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm writing a function called printField. This function takes an `int` and a `string` as arguments and then then prints a field like this `"Derp..."` with this: `printField 7 "Derp"`. When the field consists of digits the output should be "...3456".

The function I wrote looks like this:

```
printField :: Int -> String -> String
printField x y = if isDigit y 
                 then concat(replicate n ".") ++ y
                 else y ++ concat(replicate n ".")
                 where n = x - length y
```

This obviously isn't working. The error I get from GHC is:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
    Expected type: Char
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of `isDigit', namely `y'
    In the expression: isDigit y
    In the expression:
      if isDigit y then
          concat (replicate n ".") ++ y
      else
          y ++ concat (replicate n ".")
```

I can't get it to work :(. Can anyone help me out? Please keep in mind that I'm new to Haskell and functional programming in general.

Comment: `isDigit` has type `Char -> Bool` but `y` has type `String` which is an alias for `[Char]`, so `isDigit y` does not type check.

Answer (score 1):

```
isDigit :: Char -> Bool
```

---

in `printField x y` we have that `y :: [Char]` so you want to know if **every** `Char` is a digit (making a number). We use `all isDigit y`

Also, you did `concat(replicate n ".")`,

we have `"." :: [Char]` and `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`

so `replicate 2 "." :: [[Char]]`.

Just use `'.' :: Char`

---

**The final code would be**

```
import Data.Char

printField :: Int -> String -> String
printField x y = if all isDigit y
    then (replicate n '.') ++ y
    else y ++ (replicate n '.')
    where n = x - length y
```

---

Could make it *prettier*

```
import Data.Char

printField :: Int -> String -> String
printField x y = if all isDigit y
    then dots ++ y
    else y ++ dots
    where
        dots = replicate n '.'
        n = x - length y
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: first, you don't need the calls to `concat`.  Second, you probably want to say something like `if all isDigit y` -- `isDigit` is of type `Char -> Bool` and `y` is a `String`, i.e. `[Char]`, so you need to do something to make a function of type `String -> Bool`.  The `all` function from the Prelude takes a function of type `a -> Bool` and returns   a function of type `[a] -> Bool` that returns `True` if all the elements of the list you pass it satisfy your predicate.